# Building a jump-table for boto3 clients/methods

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I'm trying to build a jumptable of API methods for a variety of boto3 clients, so I can pass an AWS service name and a authn/authz low-level boto3 client to my utility code and execute the appropriate method to get a list of resources from the AWS service.

I'm not willing to hand-code and maintain a massive if..elif..else statement with >100 clauses.

I have a dictionary of service names (keys) and API method names (values), like this:

```
jumpTable = { 'lambda' : 'list_functions' }
```

I'm passed the service name ('lambda') and a boto3 client object ('client') already connected to the right service in the region and account I need.

I use the dict's get() to find the method name for the service, and then use a standard getattr() on the boto3 client object to get a method reference for the desired API call (which of course vary from service to service):

```
`apimethod = jumpTable.get(service)` 
`methodptr = getattr(client, apimethod)`
```

Sanity-checking says I've got a "botocore.client.Lambda object" for 'client' (that looks OK to me) and a "bound method ClientCreator._create_api_method.._api_call of <botocore.client.Lambda" for the methodptr which reports itself as of type 'method'.

None of the API methods I'm using require arguments.  When I invoke it directly:

```
'response = methodptr()'
```

it returns a boto3 ClientError, while invoking at through the client:

```
response = client.methodptr()
```

returns a boto3 AttributeErrror.

Where am I going wrong here?

I'm locked into boto3, Python3, AWS and have to talk to 100s of AWS services, each of which has a different API method that provides the data I need to gather.  To an old C coder, a jump-table seems obvious; a more Pythonic approach would be welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
client = boto3.Session().client("lambda")
methodptr = getattr(client, apimethod)
methodptr()
```

Note that the `boto3.Session()` part is required. When calling `boto3.client(..)` directly, I get a 'UnrecognizedClientException' exception.